# How to filter a cell which containing data by other list

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good day all

I have a table on a worksheet with two columns (name/ID). each column has a drop downlist data. I want to filter one column by using other drop down list.

for example when I choose a name from list in the column (name) must the other column filterd to match the selection.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

What is your Excel's Version ?

You have to select the Column Headers and click on "Data", "Filter" and "automatic filter" for XL2003
"Data", "Filter" for XL2007 and probably 2010.